# jquery ajax post undefined

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, post

I've been searched about this problem over stackoverflow, but couldn't get any answer that solves my problem.

This is even sample code in my node.js book. I don't know why this is not working and I want to sue author of this book. He gave me lot of stress.

1] Code in server.js

```
app.post('/products', function (request, response){

console.log(request.params);
var name = request.params.name;
var price = request.params.price;
var item = {
    name : name,
    price : price
};

items.push(item);

response.send({
    message : 'Data pushed',
    data : item
    });
});
```

2] Code in index.html

```
$('#post').click(function(){
     console.log($('#name').val());
     console.log($('#price').val());
     $.ajax({
        url:'/products',
        type:'post',
        dataType : 'text',
        data : {
          name : $('#name').val(),
          price : $('#price').val()
        },
        success : function(data){
          $('#output').val(data);
        }
    });
});
```

I can see correct data which I put in #name and #price in console of Chrome browser by console.log. But I can't see any data in server.js by console.log(request.params). **console.log(request.params), console.log(request.params.id), console.log(reqeust.params.price) all returns 'undefined'** 
Why does it return undefined?
I tried lots of things I searched through internet, but nothing solved. What's the problem?

Comment: in index.html, I can see the response of push.
So I see 
'Data pushed', {}

Comment: I mean, I think push is working, but having problem with its data sending

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you used [Expess](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html) in you server file?

```
var app = express();
app.use(express.bodyParser());
```

Or

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

In server js you need to use `request.body` instead of `request.params` like,

```
var name = request.body.name;
var price = request.body.price;
```

You are sending `json` from server so use `dataType : 'json'` like,

```
$.ajax({
    url:'/products',
    type:'post',
    dataType : 'json', // use json instead of text
    data : {
      name : $('#name').val(),
      price : $('#price').val()
    },
    success : function(data){ 
        console.log(data);// for name use data.data.name
        //$('#output').val(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: I just saw your answer and tried it, but still server.js returns {} when I call console.log(request.params)

Comment: and yes there is var items in upper side of whole code but I skipped it when I write the question

Comment: I just tried your updated answer, and I got TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Comment: Try `console.log(request,request.body);` to debug, you will get answer.

Comment: request.body is also undefined, I just checked it

Comment: I'm seeking for something to give me any hint in console.log(request) but yet I have no idea

Comment: Oh! It works! Thanks!! But sorry for asking more. request.body, request.param('name') and request.param('price') works, but request.params doesn't return anything.(undefined) Do I always need body-parser to use POST? and is there no way to use params? I have no idea on what body-parser does. sorry

Comment: Yes I used express and I can't load express.bodyParser() it says 'throw new Error('Most middleware (like ' + name + ') is no longer bundled with Express and must be installed separately. Please see https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware.');'

Comment: Oh I got it! I can access it by request.body.name